# How to extract a list of "copy password reset urls" for all users?

Tags: users, password

We are migrating users from a e-commerce site to a new craft commerce 2.x site.

Apparently it's a little too confusing for our customers to use the "forgot password" link to obtain a new password.

So our idea was to send them an email with their username and a link where they can directly set their password.

e.g. "user1", "https://mysite.com/actions/users/set-password?code=qwaZDk6mSa0tbnLBx8U4WkTnTBclK1ZZ&id=779e05ca-5c39-4f66-a56c-9a431bd0b355"

Is it possible to obtain these links programmatically.

We have about 800 users, so copy/pasting them would be very tedious.

any hints?

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of `elements/User` that you want to get the password reset URL for, you can loop through them and call this for each one:

```
$url = Craft::$app->getUsers()->getPasswordResetUrl($user)'
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do this in a template. I've discovered that the password reset link is a combination of the "uid" and a code: 
`/actions/users/set-password?code=<code>&id=<uid>`. I can fetch the uid with the following code: `{% set users = craft.users().status(null).addSelect(['users.uid']).all() %}`, but where does this "code" come from?

Comment: I am sorry... I've discovered that you can use: `{{ craft.app.getUsers.getPasswordResetUrl(user) }}`. Works like a charm! Thanks!